# Does drinking alcohol and smoking marijuana at the same time cause any trouble?

Tags: psychology, alcohol, marijuana

I've not quite done it, because I don't smoke pot often when once I did earlier on this year involved with alcohol but it was very long before I drank.It gave me a vibration in my head and a craving for lot of water and food on the very next morning.

Comment: Hello. This question isn't quite suitable for the format of this website; We only investigate "notable" claims (e.g. "Nota McAbleperson said that every time you smoke Marijuana, a kitten dies. Is this true?" vs "I smoked Marijuana yesterday and my cat died. Does smoking Marijuana cause kittens to die?")

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Cubic It's more based on psychology. I forgot to add the terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This psychology today article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/ending-addiction-good/201405/the-dangers-combining-alcohol-and-marijuana) suggest that combining both can lead to severe effects and even death.
Consuming too much alcohol usually leads to vomiting, as the body is getting rid of the toxins, but since marijuana prevents vomiting the outcome can be death.

Comment: Note this article doesn't provide any evidence to support their claims,  and admits there is little research to back them.

Comment: This is in contradiction to pot users lore that this combination is especially prone to make you vomit.

Comment: Anecdotally if you smoke before drinking you can mix them somewhat but don't overdo it. But if you drink a lot then smoke you'll probably vomit. The linked article also has it: The danger of drinking before smoking is severe illness. A side effect of smoking marijuana, called “greening out”, is more likely to occur if a person drinks alcohol before smoking.